# How to get proper indentation from sass to css?

Tags: sass, c9.io

I am a new sass user. when i am typing in style.scss and it converted to style.css, the stylesheet indentations is too poor. The style.css did not get the proper indentation.

I am using [c9.io](http://www.c9.io) here is the [screenshot](http://prnt.sc/c6i06s) of my style.scss and style.css

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Sass has a few [output styles](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style). It sounds like you're looking for the "expanded" style.

**nested**

```
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000; }
  #main p {
    width: 10em; }
```

**expanded**

```
#main {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
#main p {
  width: 10em;
}
```

**compact**

```
#main { color: #fff; background-color: #000; }
#main p { width: 10em; }
```

**compressed**

```
#main{color:#fff;background-color:#000}#main p{width:10em}.huge{font-size:10em;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline}
```

I'm not familiar with the c9 editor but if there's a settings page (maybe try the cog icon in the bottom right of the editor), you may be able to toggle it there.